# VBA Making chart from array - problem with missing values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a line chart with markers. The data is being created in code into array and this array put into chart.

Problem is that there's missing values represented in array as EMPTY.

When plotting the two point that do exist are being connected with line.
The option is selected to plot gaps if cells is empty.

Serie formula shows EMPTY as #N/A.

XValues=={"11/28/2016","12/5/2016","12/12/2016","12/19/2016","12/26/2016","1/2/2017","1/9/2017","1/16/2017","1/23/2017","1/30/2017","2/6/2017","2/13/2017","2/20/2017","2/27/2017"}

Values ={125.15,93.875,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,42,125,48.5714285714285,137,127.285714285714,81.6428571428571,89.9375,69.5,65.6428571428571,75.5,47.1666666666666}

Tried replacing with 0, "", NaN, nothing works. I want to have a break in plotting line.

I have existing value then serie of missing values and then some value.
I noticed that if serie starts with missing values it's plotting fine with gap.
Otherwise not working.

```
For i = LBound(p_data, 1) + 1 To UBound(p_data, 1)
    sSerieName = p_data(i, 0)

    If sSerieName <> "" Then

        Dim serie() As Variant
        Dim w As Long
        w = 0
        For j = LBound(labels) To UBound(labels)
            ReDim Preserve serie(j): serie(j) = p_data(i, j + 1)
        Next j
        If Not Len(Join(serie, "")) = 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
            With p_chart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .XValues = labels
                .Values = serie
                .Name = sSerieName                    
            End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code or even better a [mcve].

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` best not to do this, you can be skipping the error, you are trying to find

Comment: Can you show what `xvalues` and and `serie` end up as please.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav added above

Comment: Have you tried, replacing the errors with the string "empty" or Null.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav both results as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible when setting the values etc by arrays.  It seems to resolve `Empty` as N/A.  I have tried the following solution, which would involve you keeping a tally of where these empty's happen.  So for example, in this case, I have substituted the previous value for my empty, at point 3, and used the following

Values wanted are 10,20,EMPTY,40

```
With s.NewSeries
    .XValues = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
    .Values = Array(10, 20, 20, 40)
    .Points(3).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With
```

The full solution I tried is as follows

```
Sub x()

Dim s As SeriesCollection
Dim lc As Long
Dim aTest() As Variant
Dim serie As String

aTest = Array(15, 20, Empty, 40)

Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection

For lc = 0 To UBound(aTest)

    If aTest(lc) = "" Then      '   <--- record these lc values to hide points
        If lc = 0 Then
            aTest(lc) = 0
        Else
            aTest(lc) = aTest(lc - 1)
        End If
    Else
    End If

Next lc

With s.NewSeries
    .XValues = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
    .Values = aTest
    .Points(3).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Had similar idea. Thanks a lot!